# What does the "~" notation mean with regard to an algorithm's running time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I see a lot of things like ~N^2 or ~N, but I really don't know what "~" means.

Comment: Use SymbolHound to search sites with symbols: http://symbolhound.com/?q=java+~

Comment: Reading a book by Sedgewick?

Comment: In this context it would mean approximately.

Comment: Hard to say without more context, but it's semi-frequently used to mean "approximately."

Comment: Could mean "asymptotic equality" or "approximately equal" or "proportional to".

Comment: @Blender That link doesn't really help for this question (but may be useful outside the context of the question). Also, in the given context, the symbol doesn't **actually** have anything to do with Java, even though the question was tagged as such.

Answer (score 5):

A tilde (~) in front of an expression is often used to mean *approximately* or roughly equivalent. I think this is most likely the meaning you are encountering.

Comment: Thx a lot! Now everything makes sense.

Comment: I wonder what the mathematical definition of "approximately" or "roughly equivalent" is. Something to allow us to, conclusively, say "these functions are roughly equivalent" or "these functions are not".

Answer (score 1):

[`~` means asymptotically equal to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

In (hopefully) more understandable terms, it roughly means **the dominant term with constant factors included** (as opposed to something like Big-O notation, in which constant factors don't play a role).

Or, more generally, `f(n) ~ g(n)` if and only if `f(n)` and `g(n)` have the same dominant term (including the constant factors).

The dominant term is the biggest term as n -> ∞.

Some examples may explain it better:

```
5n^2 + 10n + 15 ~ 5n^2

I haven't really seen this used, but also valid:
5n^2 + 10n + 15 ~ 5n^2 + 22n + 7

Not valid:
5n^2 + 10n + 15 ~ n^2
```

In contrast to Big-O notation, where you can replace the `5` with anything, and Big-O is just an upper bound, so you can use any asymptotically bigger term:

```
5n^2 + 10n + 15 ∈ O(n^2)

The simplest, smallest representation, as above, is preferred, but also valid:
5n^2 + 10n + 15 ∈ O(999999n^2)
5n^2 + 10n + 15 ∈ O(458279n^2 + 3289n + 77)
5n^2 + 10n + 15 ∈ O(n^3)

Not valid:
5n^2 + 10n + 15 ∈ O(999999n)
```